# Laravel 5: Can't POST to route resource

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a route resource `Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController');` and when I run `route:list` I can see POST is available.

```
+--------+----------+--------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                      | Name             | Action                                                       | Middleware      |
+--------+----------+--------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | projects                 | projects.index   | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@index                | auth            |
|        | POST     | projects                 | projects.store   | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@store                | auth            |
|        | GET|HEAD | projects/create          | projects.create  | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@create               | auth            |
|        | GET|HEAD | projects/{projects}      | projects.show    | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@show                 | auth            |
|        | PUT      | projects/{projects}      | projects.update  | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@update               | auth            |
|        | PATCH    | projects/{projects}      |                  | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@update               | auth            |
|        | DELETE   | projects/{projects}      | projects.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@destroy              | auth            |
|        | GET|HEAD | projects/{projects}/edit | projects.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\ProjectsController@edit                 | auth            |
+--------+----------+--------------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

When I am at `/projects/create` (shows my form) and hit my submit button, I get an error saying:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 201:
  at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE')) in RouteCollection.php line 188
```

Is it perhaps how I am defining my `<form>` tag? Am I not using the correct action?

`<form method="post" action="">`

I also tried `<form method="post" action="{{ url('projects/store') }}">`

Sorry, I am a noob to laravel!

Comment: Whoever voted to close my question because it is off topic, please explain

Comment: Your routes only specify `GET` and `HEAD` methods as permitted for `/projects/create` but you are using a `POST` method to submit your form. Adjust your routes file to accept `POST` too.

Comment: I understand that now, thanks. @Zerp pointed out my action needed to be pointing to simply `/projects` in order for me to store

Comment: You can of course solve the issue any way you want but the bottom line is that exception was raised because you used a method which had no definition in the routes file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be `POST`ing to the resource url, not resource/create.

In other words just make sure the action of your form is `action="/projects"` not `action="/projects/create"`

Edit:
I will leave this here as it is kind of relevant, and because I originally posted it, but with the forewarning that it is overkill and a lot of irrelevant code for someone just starting.

For instance, here's a blade snippet from one of my sites:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Create a Project')

@section('content')

    <h3>Create a Project</h3>

    <hr/>

    {!! Form::open(['action'=>'ProjectController@store']) !!}

        @include('forms/partials/edit_form', ['submit_button_label' => 'Add Project'])

    {!! Form::close() !!}


    @include('errors.list')

@endsection
```

Comment: Ah, that did it! I should probably start creating my forms that way too rather than HTML. Thank you @Zerp. I will accept you answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks. I'd recommend the "Laravel 5 Fundamentals" series on laracasts.com if youre looking to learn more.

Comment: I actually watched all of them a couple months back when I had some downtime. I am actually using L5 in a real project now so I should maybe watch for a refresher.

Comment: Best way to avoid common pitfalls with forms in Laravel 5 is to use `FormBuilder` (http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.html) as Zerp already suggested.

Comment: yep, I just installed it in my project

Answer (score 3):

Laravel actually uses `method="POST"` in all `<form>` tags.

What you need is the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
```

`DELETE` can be replaced with the other HTTP verbs too (PUT, PATCH, UPDATE, etc)

Comment: Or you could use the form helpers and it does all that for you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why I would need a DELETE if I am wanting to store something in the DB?

Comment: You don't.  Just an example of syntax.  Thought you might have been confused as to how to set the method.  Re-reading the question I think this answer is rather pointless.

Comment: Gotcha, I am using the form builder now so it makes it pretty easy to set the method. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I see that since the last reply Laravel has been updated. Anyway, I came across the same problem today and here is how I fixed it.

Basically my routing looks like this now:

```
// Resourcing routes: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers
Route::resource('admin/photos', 'Admin\AdminPhotosController');

// need to do this to enable the store method on the following route (otherwise POST is on index when resourcing controllers)
Route::any('admin/photos/create', 'Admin\AdminPhotosController@create');
Route::post('admin/photos/create', 'Admin\AdminPhotosController@store');
```

Hope that helps someone.