# How to store variable from option value to controller and save it in database with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I'm trying to save variables from my view to controller and then save it in databases but im getting MethodNotAllowedHttpException.

Here are my view

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('absensi.store') }}">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label name="nim"><h3>NIM :</h3></label> &nbsp;
        <select name ="mahasiswasn" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-width="500px" title="Choose the Student Number">
        @foreach($nim as $nm)
          <option value="{{ $nm->nim }}">{{ $nm->nim}}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label name="matkul"><h3>&nbsp;MK :</h3></label> &nbsp;
        <select name ="matkulsn" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-width="500px" title="Choose the subject">
        @foreach($matkul as $mkl)
          <option value="{{ $mkl->nama }}">{{ $mkl->nama}}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label name="hari">Hari :</label>
        <input id="hari" name="hari" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label name="status">Status :</label>
        <input id="status" name="status" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <input type="submit" value="Add Absensi " class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">

    </form>
```

My Controller (AbsensiController)

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
           $this->validate($request,array(
                'nim' =>'required',
                'matkul' =>'required',
                'hari' =>'required',
                'status' =>'required'
                ));

            //store in database
            $post = new PostAbsensi;

            $post->nim = $request->get('mahasiswasn');
            $post->mk = $request->get('matkulsn');
            $post->hari = $request->get('hari');
            $post->status = $request->get('status');

            $post->save();

            Session::flash('success','data successfully saved!');

            return redirect()->route('absensi.show', $post->id);
    }
```

My Routes :

```
Route::resource('absensi','AbsensiController');
```

Please Help, thank you for your attention.

Edit :

Here are my other view(IndexAbsensi)

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('absensi.create') }}">
                      <input type="submit" value=" + Tambah Absensi " class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
                      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  </form>
```

so my thought is that when i press the button it will go to the AbsensiController@create and then return my form view, however im also getting Methodnotallowedhttpexception with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5: Can't POST to route resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598921/laravel-5-cant-post-to-route-resource)

Comment: Also, make sure you the problem does not come from your **routes.php** file: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-supplementing-resource-controllers

Comment: I would say you have an issue in your routes, could you post your whole file so we can see?

Comment: @lesssugar I checked into my route files but i couldn't find any problem. I just use "Route::resource('absensi','AbsensiController');" for that.

Comment: @rosscooper that's my only routes for that, the other one are irrelevant like Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home'); etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys, i finally found the solution. It was quite strange but somehow laravel might just execute some commented form codes in my view. I wasn't expecting that at all. I deleted the commented codes and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

can you try

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
       $this->validate($request,array(
            'nim' =>'required',
            'matkul' =>'required',
            'hari' =>'required',
            'status' =>'required'
            ));

        //store in database
        $post = new PostAbsensi;

        $post->nim = $request->mahasiswasn;
        $post->mk = $request->matkulsn;
        $post->hari = $request->hari;
        $post->status = $request->status;

        $post->save();

        Session::flash('success','data successfully saved!');

        return redirect()->route('absensi.show', $post->id);
}
```

I don't know if it posible get post request variables via $request->get("")

Answer (score 0):

***@Ahmad*** you are wrong store method uses post route. see https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes

***@Riki*** Every thing looks fine in code maybe you are overwriting route or naem of route or something like this.
can you run `php artisan route:list` by this you can see which method is for this route.

or you can use `<form method="POST" action="{{ url('absensi') }}">`

and in controller you also can use

```
$this->validate($request->all(),array(
            'nim' =>'required',
            'matkul' =>'required',
            'hari' =>'required',
            'status' =>'required'
            ));
```

Comment: HI @Usman Sharif thank's for your reply, however i tried changing with "<form method="POST" action="{{ url('absensi') }}">" and still not working. Previously i did changed the controller like that also but still no luck.

Comment: did you try `php artisan route:list`?
what method it show for route *absensi.store* ?

Comment: Oh strange
can you try to change the name of route from **absensi** to some unique like **absensi_1** because  the only reason I can guess is that you route is overwritten.